# Apparmor not starting with kernel LSM error

Tags: 10.04, apparmor

Starting apparmor on a Ubuntu Lucid Lynx gives the following:

```
user@host:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor start
 * Starting AppArmor profiles
 * AppArmor not available as kernel LSM.
   ...fail!
```

Googling a bit, I found the following bug report - marked as fixed -:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/375422

Which seems to be my exact case. My kernel is 2.6.32-21-generic. Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to get a Launchpad account if you do not already have one, then go to the bug report. Mark yourself as affected by that bug and post another comment there with your specs.

Alternatively, you could try filing your case as a new bug, but it may end up being marked as a duplicate in that case.